# sort python list by filename

Tags: python, list

There's a python list where I stored the filenames from multiple subfolders.
Here's a snapshot of the list
[image]

I tried to sort this list by using such a line

```
mylist = list_files(MAIN_DIR)
print(sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: int(x.split('/')[-1][:-4].replace('_',''))))
```

But this doesn't work and thows an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`
What I need is to sort the list by the filename (the base name) as shown in the snapshot

Comment: It looks like you should be doing `x.split('\\')` instead

Comment: I would work with `os.path.split` to avoid trouble with / and \\

Comment: You could also use `x.split('.')[0][-1]` to get the character before the file extension

Comment: @Ben Grossmann Thanks a lot. That does the trick `x.split('.')[0][-1]`. Is it possible to get sublists from the main list. I mean each similar filename would go in a sub-list

Comment: Another point `-1` means to get only one letter from the filename or I misunderstand that. The real file names are real such as `SampleTest.pdf`

Comment: This works fine as for real file names `print(sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: str(x.split('\\')[-1][:-4].replace('_',''))))`

Comment: I have the question in a separate thread on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71542240/create-sublist-from-main-python-list-by-condition

Comment: @Y I don't understand what you mean by "get sublists from the main list" or "each similar filename". Yes, the `...[-1]` gets you only the final character

Comment: Look there are subfolders in the main folder, and each subfolder has pdf files. In those subfolders, it happened a lot that there are similar pdf names, so I thought of sorting the list as you helped me. Then to create sublists from the main list `[['...\\1.pdf', '...\\1.pdf'], ['...\\2.pdf', '...\\2.pdf', '...\\2.pdf']]`. This is what I meant